# Two way synchronization mongodb database

Tags: mongodb, synchronization

I work at a company that has two locations, both locations use a software that was designed for us. Sometimes we have some issues with our internet connection for a couple of hours and the second location can't connect to our database located on our main server, we use mongodb because to store our data and thinking of replicating the same database in both locations and pushing that data at the end of the day.

I read a little about how you can only use Master-slave which doesn't let you have a two way synchronization. Any ideas of what I can do to solve this issue?

P.S. We currently use a VPN to connect to mongodb since we use sensitive data.

Comment: This is deliberately disallowed in MongoDB replication scheme since it can promote a "split brain" scenario, where the same document was modified in two different places when a network partition took place. When the partition clears and you found that there are two versions of the same document, how can you tell which version is the right one?

Comment: Didn't really think of that, are there any other document type database management systems that allow these conditions? If not then I'll have to find another alternative, I was thinking of MySQL but the problem with that is we have to add new forms every couple of months, which means we would have to create additional tables or attributes every time we add a new one.

Comment: I'm not sure about other DBMS, but any master-master deployment would need to solve the split-brain problem. It could be either last-write-wins (but again, what is "last write" in a distributed environment? System clocks could be out of sync. Lamport clock could presumably diverge in this scenario, etc.), manual intervention requiring downtime, etc. MongoDB just chooses consistency in this case instead, so failovers can be automated, and no expensive reconciliation need to take place.

Comment: Regarding your use case, it may be possible to circumvent the master-master design by using a MongoDB replica set with 3 nodes split across 3 separate data centers. This is a common use case supported by a replica set. Typically it is unlikely for a location to be unable to connect to at least 2 of 3 data centers unless there's a major network disruption that shouldn't happen often in a production environment anyway. Please see https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-elections/ and https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-architecture-geographically-distributed/ for details.